# Centering two rows of images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently inherited some (messy) code and want to center two rows of images, each row with three images each.  I have been trying to figure out why I can't get them to center.

Here's my HTML

```
    <div class="top1">
        <div class="container" style="background-color:#fff; padding-top:10%; padding-bottom:400px; padding-top:15px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 inspire_others">
                    <img style="position: relative;" class="img-responsive" src="images/1.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 inspire_others" style="margin-top:5%">
                    <img style="position: relative;" class="img-responsive" src="images/2.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" style="margin-top:5%;" /> <!--width="220px" height="240px"-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 inspire_others">
                    <img style="position: relative;" class="img-responsive" src="images/3.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px;">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 inspire_others">
                    <img style="position: relative;" class="img-responsive" src="images/4.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" style="margin-top:5%;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 inspire_others" style="margin-top:5%">
                    <img style="position: relative;" class="img-responsive" src="images/5.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 inspire_others">
                    <img style="position: relative;" class="img-responsive" src="images/6.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" style="margin-top:5%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        <br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned up your code, and you need `col-md-4` instead `col-md-2` because bootstrap by default has 12 columns so 12 / 3 is 4. and add `margin:auto` in `img` to center image because `img` in bootstrap is already `display:block`

```css
[class^="col"] {
  border: green 1px solid
}
img {
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="top1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 inspire_others">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 inspire_others">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
        <!--width="220px" height="240px"-->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 inspire_others">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 inspire_others">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 inspire_others">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 inspire_others">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow. I missed the col-md-4 thing which cleared up my problem.  Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Good news! There's actually a really easy way to center the images.

tldr; - Just add the code below in a <style> tag:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Long Story
It turns your .row div into a flexbox (more info here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). 
The justify-content property centers all the divs inside .row (and the images in the divs).

Comment: why use flexbox here when the bootstrap itself can fix the issue?